# Ul, liで3分割された個別のイメージの縦横比率を黄金比にする方法

Tags: css

畏れ入ります。

スタイルシートでこのように

```
#top_btn ul li {
    display: block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:32%;
    height:90px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
    border:3px solid #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #755600;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #755600;
    line-height:1.1;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:relative;
```

並べて３分割横ならべで各々のliで指定している図は並べると縦横比101*210位になってしまい
[image: 縦横比101*210位になってしまい]
一般に広く用いられていると思われる黄金比1:1.618位に各々のイメージ
を直す方法は御座いますでしょうか？

宜しくお願い致します(m_m)。

---

追加　11/4

下記お答え頂いて下記表示されているアイコン自体をリサイズしましたが上手く行きません
でした・・・。とりあえず別の事をしていたので解答自体は取り消しませんが、その下のアドバイスを試して見ます。とりあえず、htmlは以下です。(m_m)

```
<div id="wrapper" class="inner clearfix top">
<article class="clearfix">
<div id="content">
<div id="top_btn">
<ul class="clearfix">
<li id="about"><a href="about/index.html"><span class="l1">***</span>ついて
</a></li>
<li id="area"><a href="area/index.html"><span class="l1">****</span>***</a>
</li>
<li id="voice" class="mr0"><a href="voice/index.html"><span class="l1">***
</span>***</a></li>
<li id="try"><a href="try/index.html"><span class="l1">***</span>***</a>
</li>
<li id="price"><a href="price/index.html">料金</a></li>
<li id="faq" class="mr0"><a href="faq/index.html"><span class="l1">***
</span>***</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

(m_m)(m_m)。

Comment: 因みにどうしても解らないです。インラインで例えば個別にHeight, Width指定するとどかどかと崩れてしまい、更に他とのスペースの関係で一切無効になります・・・・。

Comment: 「background-size:162% auto;」も無効・・・。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMLがないので詳細が不明ですが、元々の画像ファイルサイズを希望の比率にするのが一番効率的かと思います。

画像サイズを変更できない場合は希望の比率で透過pngなどを作成・表示し、
背景画像として画像を設定してみるのではいかがでしょうか。
background-sizeにcoverを指定することで背景領域を覆う最小サイズで表示されます。

```
<li><img src="hoge.png" alt=""></li>

<style>
    #top_btn ul li {
        background-image: url(image.png);
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

いずれにせよ、もう少し細かく質問を書いていただけるとよりわかりやすく回答できるかもしれません。

Comment: 有り難うございます。試してみます(m_m)

Comment: 解決したようであれば解答の承認をお願いします。

Comment: すみません。決算時期で会計もやっているのでとりあえず「良いアドバイス」として答えとさせて頂きませんか？有る意味失礼で申し訳御座いませんが(m_m)。